# Split one column into groups, and summarize another column of each group

Tags: r, aggregate

The data frame is

```
A    B
2.3  4.1
1.2  7.6
0.5  3.2
1.5  2.3
```

I'd like to split column A into three groups and summarize the column B.
The result would be

```
X    Y
0   3.2
1   9.9
2   4.1
```

I searched the question, but only found the answers like https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8225/how-to-summarize-data-by-group-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cut` and `aggregate`:

```
> aggregate(B ~ cut(A, breaks=3), mydf, sum)
  cut(A, breaks = 3)   B
1        (0.498,1.1] 3.2
2          (1.1,1.7] 9.9
3          (1.7,2.3] 4.1
```

For finer control, look at the many arguments you can pass to `cut`. For nicer output, you can create a new column that has the "cut" values (so that the column name is not `cut(A, breaks = 3)`).

Comment: Can you help me with another question as I described bottom?